# result decimal places javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code which works perfectly for what I need, which is to calculate a mean reciprocal from two numbers. But can't figure out how to make it output and round the result to 4 decimal places. Please assist.

```
    function calc(obj) {
    var avcount = 0, sum = 0, val
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
     for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
     if (elems[i].name.match(/^datup/)) {
         val = parseFloat(elems[i].value)
         if (val) { sum += val }  // taofi le vaega gaogao
         avcount += 1
     }
  }
     if (avcount>0) {
     document.getElementById("faitau").value = 1/(sum/avcount) //I need 4 decimal places here
      }
     else { alert("Leai se mea e tusi") }  // leai se vaega amata 'datup'
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) what you are looking for?

```
document.getElementById("faitau").value = (1/(sum/avcount)).toFixed(4)
```

Comment: But that doesn't round, it just chops it off

Comment: Yes sir, I think it does, appreciate the assist, I'd tried this but messed up the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`.toFixed` and `Math.round`:

```
Number.prototype.roundTo = function (d) { return +(Math.round(this + "e+"+d)  + "e-"+d); }
```

Add the above code to the top of your JavaScript. Then you can do:

```
value.roundTo(3); // 3 is the amount of decimal places to round too
```

---

## Examples

```
3.444.roundTo(2); // 3.44
3.563.roundTo(2); // 3.56
3.345.roundTo(2); // 3.35
3.183422.roundTo(4); // 3.1834
```